# Join anonymous type in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

i do have 2 c# declaration table , it column initialise during the creation of the program.

i wanted to join this table base on its UserID and UserName.

My Code is like following

```
from nSJL in UserList.AsEnumerable()
join SJL in UserListOnline.AsEnumerable()
on
new { nSJL.Field<int>("UserID"), nSJL.Field<string>("UserName") }
equals
new { nSJL.Field<int>("UserID"), nSJL.Field<string>("UserName") }
into sjList
```

in this code i am getting the error

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Anyway to join anonymous type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the names for the anonymous type properties:

```
from nSJL in UserList.AsEnumerable()
join SJL in UserListOnline.AsEnumerable()
on
new { UserID = nSJL.Field<int>("UserID"),
      UserName = nSJL.Field<string>("UserName") }
equals
new { UserId = SJL.Field<int>("UserID"),
      UserName = SJL.Field<string>("UserName") }
into sjList
```

Note that I've also changed the right hand side of the join to use `SJL` rather than `nSJL` too, as otherwise it's invalid. It would help your code's clarity if you'd use rather more meaningful names though...

Answer (score 6):

```
from nSJL in UserList.AsEnumerable()
join SJL in UserListOnline.AsEnumerable()
on
new{  UserID = nSJL.Field<int>("UserID"), UserName = nSJL.Field<string>("UserName") }
equals
new { UserID = nSJL.Field<int>("UserID"), UserName = nSJL.Field<string>("UserName") } into sjList
```

You weren't declaring the field names for your anonymous type.