# Linq, groupjoin on multiple fields and substring matching

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do a group join([GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2)) on a couple of fields including a string 'like'.

Let's say
Human - {Name, Size, FullAddress} and
Item - {OwnerName, City, Size}

let's say I go for a normal join

```cs
var result = from h in Human
                join it in Item on 
                    h.OwnerName equals it.OwnerName
                where h.Size == it.Size ||
                      h.Address.startsWith(it.City)   
                select new {human = h, Item = it};
```

I guess I can pretend that it works and gives all items that belong to a person with the same name and fit them, or are in the same city.

But trying to go for the group join kinda stops me in my tracks:

```cs
var result = from h in Human
                join it in Item on 
                    h.OwnerName equals it.OwnerName into g
                where h.Size == it.Size ||
                      h.Address.startsWith(it.City)   
                select new {human = h, Items = g};
```

ASFAIK it(item) is no longer defined for the 'where' context.
If I did not have the 'LIKE%' part(startsWith) I probably would have been able to use the anonymous class helped join(as in this [answer/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294061/join-anonymous-type-in-linq))

I am trying to figure some compact solution for this, without going back to the not grouped join and grouping them manually.

Comment: You do not need 'g'.  Just use Items = it

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the answer. I must admit that I have some issues understanding your answer, are you saying that there is no way to make the groups so I should use the first query from my question?

Comment: Into doesn't do a Group (see msnd : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/into).  I usually group by adding parenthesis around the from : (from ......select ......).GroupBy(x => ........)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, my bad. I was talking about [GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join), not GroupBy.

Comment: The only thing a group Join does is when you do a left outer join and want to find the items in B when A is null.

Comment: You could put the condition on the `g` instead of on the overall match, since it is `g` you are trying to constrain, e.g. `Items = g.Where(it => it.Size == h.Size && h.Address.StartsWith(it.City))`.

Comment: I kinda moved away from this code, so I  have some issues validating this but @NetMage, your answer seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jdweng You're wrong about `into`. It *does* group because the compiler converts `join - into` into `GroupJoin`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold : You are referencing your own posting.  My link is a Microsoft Document.   Yes Microsoft does make errors.  But to say I'm wrong?

Comment: @jdweng "Into doesn't do a Group" Yeah, but here it's used with `join`. That means `GroupJoin`. If not wrong then *at best* is highly confusing to say that grouping doesn't occur and then recommend `GroupBy`.